# What dried food can I take across the American border from Canada?

Tags: food-and-drink, borders, camping, banff

We will be driving from Banff to Glacier National Park while on our camping trip and I was told to be careful with taking food across the border. We don't eat meat so that's one less issue and I already know that many fresh fruits/veggies can get complicated so I'm only thinking of taking dry stuff across (mostly grains but possibly also dried veggies).

My plan at first was to stock up at BulkBarn in Calgary since they have tons of stuff and you can just take what you need but I'm afraid that since the packaging is generic and unsealed that it might cause more problems. What are the criteria to be able to take dried food across the border?

Comment: The list of foods you *can't* take is probably smaller than the list of foods you can.

Comment: From my experience, if you are driving across and are a US or Canadian citizen, it will almost certainly be a breeze going across the border. They will almost certainly not ever check you unless you're very unlucky or look really suspicious.

Answer (score 3):

Dried fruits are specifically permissible:

> **Dried Fruit**- things like apricots, barberry, currants, dates, figs, gooseberries, peaches, prunes, raisins, tomatillos, and zereshk

Fresh fruit and vegetables **from Canada** are ok:

> Fruits and vegetables grown in Canada are generally admissible, **if they have labels identifying them as products of Canada**.

The same goes for processed foods:

> Food products from Canada, including pet food and fresh (frozen or chilled), cooked, canned or otherwise processed products containing beef, veal, bison, and cervid (e.g. deer, elk, moose, caribou etc.) are now permitted from Canada in passenger baggage. Products containing sheep, lamb, or goat will not be allowed entry.

[All information from the US government](https://web.archive.org/web/20111014232759/https://help.cbp.gov/app/answers/detail/a_id/82/%7E/travelers-bringing-food-into-the-u.s.-for-personal-use).